# JPA: Issue on batch insert using persist()

Tags: jpa

I am using below code to insert the record into database,

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = getEmf();
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //Get the Transaction
    EntityTransaction trx = em.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    for ( int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
       //Create new Object and persist
        Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
        em.persist(customer);
        //Once its reach the 1000 size do commit
        if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) { 
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
            trx.commit();
        }
    }
    em.close();
```

The above code is working fine when I don’t have any duplicate value in database as like new Customer object. If I have any duplicate value for Customer in database I am getting “SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException”. 
Here I am using persist () to insert the record into database for performance issue. If I use merge (), its working fine. but its need more time to complete the task.
In persist () case is there any option to identify which is duplicate record (i.e get duplicate record information)?
If more than one duplicate record present in DB, is there any option to identify which are duplicates records?

Answer (score 0):

I believe avoiding adding duplicates is meant to be the application code's responsibility.

You could save a list of the customers you have sent to persist(), then prior to committing, query the db using a JPQL query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(c)
FROM Customer c
WHERE c in (:customers)
```

and send the list to the customers bind variable.  Check ther result, and if the count is > 0, you know a customer has been duplicated and will cause a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException on commit.

Alternately, use a call to `em.find(customer, Customer.class)` prior to adding the em to the Persistence Context with the persist call.  If it exists, don't add it.